# How to JavaScript if image height match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="image.gif" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById("myImage").height);
if (image.height.match("200")) {
//click button or something
```

i want to check if the image height match 200.

Comment: Maybe you want, `var imageHeight = $('#myImage').height(); if (imageHeight === 200) {...`

Comment: thank you for fast answer, i will check it now

Comment: @Tushar i try but its not working. what i did wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/aow6me7s/1/

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aow6me7s/2/). Mixing JS & jQ. Image height is not set, so the `if` condition will evaluate to false.

Comment: @Tushar work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="image.gif" />
```

JS

```
function changeImage() {
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { 
    if (img.height == "200") {
    // some code is here
    };
img.src = document.getElementById("myImage").src;
}
```